# WiFi Disabled by Hardware Switch?

Tags: linux, networking

I've just installed Debian on a Lenovo X130e Thinkpad.

I had some issues with the firmware for the wireless card, and fixed them; but now I've run into an issue that has rather stumped me:

```
WiFi is disabled by hardware switch
```

When the device ran Windows, WiFi could be turned on and off via <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but that now does nothing, I've had a good look for another physical switch, including with a screwdriver, and could not find one.

- `rfkill list all` showed WiFi to be Hard Blocked.
- `rfkill unblock all` did nothing.

The wireless device is identified as `wlp2s0b1`.

I have no internet connection on the laptop, but can copy files over on a USB from another PC if need be.

I have posted this on reddit, but got no solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Wireless is not disabled in BIOS. Nor is anything else in the networking tab.

**EDIT2:**

In single user mode <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> still does nothing, but `rfkill list all` shows WiFi as unblocked. Upon logging back in normally, WiFi is blocked again. What can I do about this?

Comment: Just had a look, not disabled in bios. Used to work running windows.

Comment: one other thought ... perhaps Fn+F5 interacts with hardware directly in windows, but the key combination is somehow being trapped by linux ... another thought ... download Knoppix an run it from thumb drive, see if that works

Comment: boot linux into single user mode ... that will prevent desktop manager from starting along with a lot of programs that are associated with the DM ... see if Fn+F5 is operational then

Comment: In single user mode Fn+F5 still does nothing, but rfkill list all shows WiFi as unblocked. Upon logging back in normally WiFi is blocked again. What can I do about this?

Comment: FIXED! If you have the same issue look here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M&t=3s

Comment: @Mblizzard I converted your answer to a comment since posting a link to a 10-minute long video isn't actually answering the question. Could you please post an answer that shows the actual steps you used to fix your problem instead of a video?

Comment: Thanks for the correction terdon, here's a bit more of an explanation. The process involved covering pin 20 of the wireless adapter so that it does not receive an input from the Aeroplane mode button.